# Planned shutdown is blocked by a pipeline that runs Cypress tests within a Docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins setup where I'm running Cypress tests within a Docker container. The Docker container is built on top of the Cypress Docker image and is executed as part of a pipeline job on Jenkins. This pipeline job is described using the declarative pipeline syntax. However, I'm encountering an issue during planned Jenkins shutdowns.

Whenever Jenkins initiates a planned shutdown, it seems to get blocked waiting for the Cypress tests to complete within the Docker container. This delay in job completion is causing disruptions to our maintenance schedule.

Is there a way to handle Jenkins shutdowns more gracefully while running Cypress tests within Docker containers? Are there any specific configurations or best practices I should follow to ensure that Jenkins shutdowns don't get blocked by long-running Cypress tests?